# Secure and unhurt

Tags: riddle, word

> I'm fast asleep, I'm secure and unhurt.
>   The argument's valid, I firmly assert.
>   A body of water, a deafening alert,
>   a tool used by doctors, I'm found in concerts.

What am I?

Comment: Loved this one!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are

> Sound

I'm fast asleep, I'm secure and unhurt.

> **Sound** asleep, Safe and **sound**.

The argument's valid, I firmly assert.

> A **sound** argument in logic - An argument is sound if and only if it is valid and all its premises are true.

A body of water, a deafening alert,

> [A sound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_(geography)) - a large sea or ocean inlet larger than a bay, deeper than a bight, and wider than a fjord, an alarm **sound**

a tool used by doctors, I'm found in concerts.

> [Ultrasound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrasound), **Sound**/ Stereo system in concerts.

Comment: Exceptional.  The body of water thing really threw me off.  Bravo Q&A. +1 +1